# Equivalence of Sigma-Fields generated by Random variables

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I have random variables $C_0,...,C_n$ and $S_0,...,S_n$ where $C_0=S_0$ and $S_i=C_i -C_{i-1}$ for $i>0$.
My question is whether the corresponding sigma-fields are equivalent i.e. $\sigma(C_0,..,C_n)=\sigma(S_0,...,S_n)$ or not?

My own guess is that they should be equal because I can construct the RV $S_i$ from the $C_i$ and the other way around. Therefore if I take a set which is measurable in the one sigma field it also should be in the other. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything. The two $\sigma-$ fields are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing nothing. The two $\sigma$-algebras are the same, and your reasoning is correct.

- Let's consider a more general case. Let $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ be a measurable map between measurable spaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, and let $X : \Omega \to \mathcal{X}$ be a random element in $\mathcal{X}$. Then

  $$ \sigma(f(X)) \subseteq \sigma(X). $$

  Thinking of $f$ as "processing of information", this inclusion makes very much sense, since we can only lose information when processing it. The proof is also very straightforward.
- Now in your case, the map

  $$ \Phi(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n) = (c_0, c_1 - c_0, \ldots, c_n - c_{n-1}) $$

  that converts $C = (C_0,\ldots,C_n)$ to $S = \Phi(C) = (S_0, \ldots, S_n)$ is bi-measurable, in the sense that both $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ are measurable. So, we have

  $$ \sigma(S) = \sigma(\Phi(C)) \subseteq \sigma(C) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sigma(C) = \sigma(\Phi^{-1}(S)) \subseteq \sigma(S),$$

  proving the equivalence.

Comment: Missing something in the first sentence :-)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! I was a bit in a hurry when writing it up. I hope I corrected all the typos, but if it is still missing anything, please let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much!